# Testing if elements in an array are equal regardless of order or frequency

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have multiple test arrays that have to pass through a method I'm writing.  I can't for the life of me figure out why this is failing.

Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < testArray1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < testArray1.length; j++){
            if (testArray1[i].equals(testArray2[j])){
                System.out.println(testArray1[i]);
                testArray2[j] = null;
                counter++;
                i++;
            }
        }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is have the double loop test for one element from `testArray1` and once it's found

- have that entry set to null (in the case that it's a repeated entry)
- increase the counter (which I'm using later to compare if the number of entries counted as found equals the number of entries in the array thus making the arrays equal)
- and increase `i` so that it skips to the next entry since the remaining ones don't need to be tested

Doing this I get the output of:

```
Bag{Size:4 [Jill] [John] [Jack] [Jack] }
Bag{Size:4 [Jack] [Jill] [John] [Jack] }
Jill

John

Jack

counter: 3 Array size: 4
```

My problem is that the last and final `Jack` entry isn't tested at all.

Another thing is that I'm not sure if I should be resetting my `j` counter.  I'm assuming that the `j` for loop doesn't reset once I increment the `i` counter.  I tried to set `j = 0` after `counter++` but doing that broke the program with an ArrayOutOfBounds for `i` for god knows what reason.

EDIT: I just realized why it's out of bounds for `j=0`.  The loop finds the last entry, sets `j`, but also increases `i` to 5... I think?  Still not sure how to get this test to run how I want it to though.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: 1. Where is `testArray1` and `testArray2` declared? 2. Why `testArray2[j] = null;`? 3. Where is `counter` initialized? 4. Why `i++;` at the end of the loop?

Comment: @Chris Gong Expected output test is one of each array entry since it should only print them when they are found.

Comment: @nullpointer this is part of a much larger program.  I'm only testing this one method.  Also, as I've stated I'm setting it equal to null so it doesn't test one entry more than once.  i++ is so I can skip the rest of the entries once the needed one is found.  I thought I wrote all that in the post?

Comment: But your printing each entry 4 times?

Comment: Whoops, I just realized why... Yeah idk why I did that.  Still, I'm not sure why it doesn't test the final array entry.

Comment: Shouldn't ` for (int j = 0; j < testArray1.length; j++){` be: ` for (int j = 0; j < testArray2.length; j++){` ?

Comment: Since you're no longer printing out the entries, what should the expected output be now?

Comment: @Chris Gong Sorry about that, I formatted it properly.  End result should be all 4 names printed and tested.

Comment: @mxalex does it make any difference considering both arrays are the same length?

Comment: if you want to print out one of each entry, then try getting rid of `i++` in the if statement

Comment: @Chris Gong Man, I dunno whats with me but I've been staring at this for too long.  Thanks!  I dunno why I even tried with the i++ if I set the entries equal to null

Comment: I'll be posting an answer very shortly to better explain where i think you got confused

Comment: @392781  It makes a difference if it turns out the second array isn't the same length; using the relevant array's length to loop through will expose that.

Comment: @mcalex I know, but this only tests arrays that are the same length.  I have another if-statement that wasn't really relevant to the question that tests for length before anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to explain better -

> ```
> Bag{Size:4 [Jill] [John] [Jack] [Jack] }
> Bag{Size:4 [Jack] [Jill] [John] [Jack] }
> JillJillJillJill  i=0, j=1
> nullnullnullnull  and you do a i++ , so i=1,  counter = 1 
> JohnJohnJohnJohn  i=1, j=2, counter = 2
> nullnullnullnull  and you do a i++ , so i=2,  counter = 2
> JackJackJackJack  i=2, j=3, counter = 3
> nullnullnullnull  and you do a i++ , so i=3,  counter = 3
> counter: 3 Array size: 4
> ```

the outermost loop wouldn't execute this for the second time(note all the above iteration is from your inner loop), since there is another incremenet `i++` within the loop making `i=4` and exiting the loop.

Hope that helps.

***Edit*** - The question seems to have changed in terms of output shared above, but the logic to be corrected still prevails.

Comment: Thank you and @Chris Gong.  I dunno why I even incremented it to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue revolves around the confusion over this inquiry

> and increase `i` so that it skips to the next entry since the remaining
>   ones don't need to be tested

Incrementing `i` in your if-statement won't end the current loop you're in to move on to the next entry in `testArray1`. It'll just increment `i` and keep checking the rest of `testArray2`. If you want to move on to the next entry in `testArray1`, you should use a `break` statement to get out of the loop iterating through `testArray2` like so,

```
for (int i = 0; i < testArray1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < testArray1.length; j++){
            if (testArray1[i].equals(testArray2[j])){
                System.out.println(testArray1[i]);
                testArray2[j] = null;
                counter++;
                break;                
            }
        }
}
```